# How do I use a USB programmer for SOT23-5 EEPROM?

Tags: i2c, eeprom, programmer

Like using the ch314 for an unknown SOT23-5 EEPROM.

Answer (score 2):

Find datasheet for the unknown EEPROM and identify connections. It's probably I2C type, but confirm.

Download "CH341A USB Mini Programmer Latest Software" and install software. Jumper and schematic instructions for connecting to the EEPROM should be in the .zip file.

Program the EEPROM from your hex file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer